# What is the most reliable endpoint for `/v1/history/get_actions/`

Tags: api, history

I want to get info about my account's actions So I am using the endpoint
`https://history.cryptolions.io/v1/history/get_actions/` also add the params required. But my question here is some time it takes too long to respond. So there are `different end point for different BP`, How would one know which is better to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dynamic and constantly changing list and you need to find some sources for it and keep your system updated with it.

[Here is one place](https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/) I found that lists some of the BP endpoints.

Also, note that you don't have to rely on BPs for this service. You can set up a witness node and filter it to sync and listen on the info relevant to your application. Then you can use that as the endpoint and it should be reliable since it will be connected to the BPs using the EOSIO blockchain protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the listed API end-points in [EOSDocs.io](https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/) is not enabled with history plug-in. So actions like `get_transactions` and `get_actions` are not possible.

I found `https://public.eosinfra.io` is working to date for history actions

Comment: and now its not working

Comment: Try https://nodes.get-scatter.com but you have to provide the block number

Answer (score 1):

https://eos.greymass.com:443

This one works at the time of my posting